# product filter algorithm needs improvement

Tags: jquery

I have written a basic product filter algorithm that works fine when I stick to one filter, however when I try to combine filters things go wrong.

When I uncheck a checkbox the algorithm only checks the filter of the checked checkbox, but does not check the filter of other (checked) checkboxes. I suggest you have a look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reonbrack/a7774e9L/) of my code, it will be clearer than I could explain.

I am looking for some suggestions on improving the filter algorithm

**[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reonbrack/a7774e9L/)**

If you check every checkbox and uncheck every partner all the products are hidden, but the category checkboxs are still checked so some products should be shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.product').hide();
            $(function() {
                $('.filter').on('click', function() {
                    var filter = $(this).attr("filter");
                    var data = $(this).attr("data");
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('.product').each(function (i, obj) {
                            if ($(obj).attr(filter) == data) {
                                $(obj).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('.product').each(function (i, obj) {
                            if ($(obj).attr(filter) == data) {
                                $(obj).hide();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Category</p>
    <div>
        <input class="filter" filter="category" data="boeken" type="checkbox" />
        books
    </div>

    <div>
        <input class="filter" filter="category" data="spellen" type="checkbox" />
        games
    </div>

    <div>
        <input class="filter" filter="category" data="andere" type="checkbox" />
        other
    </div>
    <p>Partners</p>
    <div>
        <input class="filter" filter="partner" data="amazon" type="checkbox" />
        amazon
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="filter" filter="partner" data="ebay" type="checkbox" />
        ebay
    </div>



    <div class="products">
        <div class="product" category="boeken" partner="amazon" />
            Product 1
        </div>
        <div class="product" category="spellen" partner="ebay" />
            Product 2
        </div>
        <div class="product" category="andere" partner="ebay"/>
            Product 3
        </div>
        <div class="product" category="andere" partner="amazon"/>
            Product 4
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, your `else if (!$(this).is(':checked'))` is unnecessary because that's the exact opposite of your `if` statement anyways. Just put `else {`.

Comment: I think instead of looking if `$(this)` is `:checked`, I would get the `:checked` value of **every** check box every time a `.filter` is clicked. Then run logic with that to display your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hide all products when a filter is clicked.
2. For `each` checked filter, show products if their data matches the filter.  See **http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/**
3. In case of multiple partners, [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) `data` on a comma, and loop through the `data` array using [**$.each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

#### Snippet

```js
$('.product').hide();

$('.filter').click(function() {
  $('.product').hide();
  $('.filter:checked').each(function() {
    var filter = $(this).attr('filter');
    var data   = $(this).attr('data').split(', ');
    $.each(data, function(index,value) {
      $('.product['+filter+'="'+value+'"]').show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Category</p>
<div><input class="filter" filter="category" data="boeken" type="checkbox" />books</div>
<div><input class="filter" filter="category" data="spellen" type="checkbox" />games</div>
<div><input class="filter" filter="category" data="andere" type="checkbox" />other</div>
<p>Partners</p>
<div><input class="filter" filter="partner" data="amazon" type="checkbox" />amazon</div>
<div><input class="filter" filter="partner" data="ebay" type="checkbox" />ebay</div>
<div><input class="filter" filter="partner" data="amazon, ebay" type="checkbox" />amazon and ebay</div>
<br>
<div class="products">
  <div class="product" category="boeken"  partner="amazon" />Product 1</div>
  <div class="product" category="spellen" partner="ebay" />Product 2</div>
  <div class="product" category="andere"  partner="ebay" />Product 3</div>
  <div class="product" category="andere"  partner="amazon" />Product 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's perfect. I have another question; is it possible to do something like `partner="amazon, ebay"` because a product might be available on both websites. Thanks again

Comment: Sure.  I've updated my answer.  I also moved the `:checked` test out of an `if` statement and into the selector itself.