# Filter Algorithm Improvement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I select **category="books"** and **partner="amazon"**  then the Product 4 is showing fine but how to hide **Product 1** ?

Please help me so that it can work properly.

```
 <script>
    $('.filter').click(function() {
      $('.product').hide();
      $('.filter:checked').each(function() {
      var filter = $(this).attr('filter');
      var data   = $(this).attr('data').split(', ');
      $.each(data, function(index,value) {
      $('.product['+filter+'="'+value+'"]').show();
      });
      });
      });
    </script>




 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p>Category</p>
    <div><input class="filter" filter="category" data="boeken" type="checkbox" />books</div> 
    <div><input class="filter" filter="category" data="spellen" type="checkbox" />games</div>
    <div><input class="filter" filter="category" data="andere" type="checkbox" />other</div>

    <p>Partners</p>
    <div><input class="filter" filter="partner" data="amazon" type="checkbox" />amazon</div>
    <div><input class="filter" filter="partner" data="ebay" type="checkbox" />ebay</div>
    <div><input class="filter" filter="partner" data="amazon, ebay" type="checkbox" />amazon and ebay</div>
   <br>
    <div class="products">
  <div class="product" category="boeken"  partner="amazon" />Product 1</div>
  <div class="product" category="spellen" partner="ebay" />Product 2</div>
  <div class="product" category="andere"  partner="ebay" />Product 3</div>
  <div class="product" category="andere"  partner="amazon" />Product 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you select books and amazon, then Product4 shouldn't appear...?

Comment: If I will select *books* then only Product 1 should be appear but when I select *books* and *amazon* then product 4 should be hide. Currenty there are two results are showing.

Comment: That's the correct logic but your question says the opposite

Comment: If I select books and amazon then only product 1 should be show. Currently there are two results are showing. See:- (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430989/product-filter-algorithm-needs-improvement/53336411#53336411)

Comment: Let me explain you Simply:- If I select country = USA and City = Maryland. Then result should be show according to both match value but currently USA & Maryland all related results are showing.

Comment: I understand what you're asking. I am saying to you that your explanation in the question is backwards to the output you expect.

Comment: Could you please correct this code so that it can work properly.

Answer (score 0):

you should compose the selector string like this:

```
$('.filter').click(function() {
    $('.product').hide();
    $('.filter:checked').each(function() {
        var filter = $(this).attr('filter');
        var data   = $(this).attr('data').split(', ');
        var selector = '.product';
        $.each(data, function(index,value) {
            selector += '['+filter+'="'+value+'"]';
        });
        $(selector).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but code is not working.  It's showing all results.

Comment: If I select books and amazon then only product 1 should be show. Currently there are two results are showing.

Comment: Please check this live:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430989/product-filter-algorithm-needs-improvement/53336411#53336411